# If route threw exception and handled is set to true, only first processor in doFinally is executed

Tags: apache-camel, apache-servicemix, blueprint-osgi

I've got a Camel Blueprint definition with two Camel contexts containing one route each.

First contexts route is invoked and in turn calls the route of the second context. Now if in the second route an Exception is thrown and the `onException` sets `handled=true`, in the first routes `doFinally` block only the first processor is invoked.

Here is my Blueprint definition:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint"
          xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd
      http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/camel-blueprint.xsd">

    <bean id="myException" class="java.lang.RuntimeException">
        <argument value="Booom" />
    </bean>

    <camelContext id="firstContext" trace="false" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
        <route id="firstRoute">
            <from uri="direct-vm:start"/>
            <doTry>
                <to uri="log:FIRST_TRY"/>
                <to uri="direct-vm:generateException"/>
                <to uri="log:SECOND_TRY"/>
                <doFinally>
                    <to uri="log:FIRST_FINALLY"/>
                    <to uri="log:SECOND_FINALLY"/>
                </doFinally>
            </doTry>
            <log message="The message contains ${body}"/>
            <to uri="mock:result"/>
        </route>
    </camelContext>

    <camelContext id="secondContext" trace="false" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
        <onException>
            <exception>java.lang.Exception</exception>
            <handled>
                <constant>true</constant>
            </handled>
        </onException>
        <route id="secondRoute">
            <from uri="direct-vm:generateException"/>
            <throwException ref="myException"/>
        </route>
    </camelContext>

</blueprint>
```

Only the `<to uri="log:FIRST_FINALLY"/>` gets printed out. I cannot see the `<to uri="log:SECOND_FINALLY"/>`. Am I missing something here? Any help is appreciated.

I am using Camel 2.10.6 inside Apache Servicemix 4.5.2.

Regards
Dominik

Comment: A good idea is to try what is told here: http://camel.apache.org/support for example to upgrade Camel and try with a later release etc.

Comment: Just found out that it is working since version 2.12.0, my only Problem is that I am not able to upgrade. As we are running inside Redhat Fuse ESB 6.0 (or Servicemix 4.5.2). Don't know if it is possible to easily update Camel  inside one of them.

Comment: Red Hat Fuse 6.0 you can use the Red Hat customer support to get a a hot-fix on current version. For SMX you have to wait for new release that supports Camel 2.12 onwards which would be SMX 4.6.0 (not released yet)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, going to checkout my options. For now I try to workaround the problem until I either get the hot-fix or SMX 4.6.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can consider using multicast [1] as a workaround for this issue.

```
<doFinally>
  <multicast>
    <to uri="log:FIRST_FINALLY"/>
    <to uri="log:SECOND_FINALLY"/>
  </multicast>
</doFinally>
```

This is not the same as pipeline processing of course, but in some cases `doFinally` block can just send two messages independently.

[1] http://camel.apache.org/multicast